# LAN messenger to chat between computers connected to different routers

Tags: windows, gratis, chat, lan

We had been using IPMSG to chat and transfer files.

Now the computer are connected to a different router. Let's say computer A is connected to router 192.168.123.1 and computer B to router 192.168.0.1.
Softros LAN Messenger did the task, but the time period has expired.

All participating computers run Windows. I need a free version at least for personal use.

Comment: I cannot test it in the way you want to use it at the moment, but if memory serves [LAN Messenger](http://lanmsngr.sourceforge.net) can do this.